# C - is char* template a special type of string?

Tags: c, string

I came across a line like

```
char* template = "<html><head><title>%i %s</title></head><body><h1>%i %s</h1>        </body></html>";
```

while reading through code to implement a web server.

I'm curious as I've never seen a string like this before - is template specifying a special type of string (I'm just guessing here because it was highlighted on my IDE)? Also, how would `strlen()` work with something like this?

Thanks

Comment: This seems normal string. Interpreting the string as template will be tasks of other part of the code and `strlen()` will work just normally.

Comment: so do %i and %s count as 2 characters each with strlen()?

Comment: `template` is nothing more than the name of the variable. (It's a keyword in C++, not in C.)

Comment: `strlen()` will give the length of the string as is, without treating the `%` specially.  If they're format specifiers for `printf()` or something like that, then the formatted output generated from it might be longer, though (but that output wouldn't be the same string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there's a null character somewhere in the initializer or an escape sequence using a `\` character, which there isn't, there's nothing special about this string.  A `%` is a normal character in a string and doesn't receive special treatment.  The `strlen` function in particular will read `%i` as two characters, i.e. `%` and `i`.  Similarly for `%s`.

In contrast, a `\` is a special character for string and denotes an escape sequence.  The `\` and the character that follows it in the string constant constitute a single character in the string itself.  For example, `\n` means a newline character (ASCII 10) and `\t` is a tab character (ASCII 8).

This string is most likely used as a format string for `printf`.  This function will read the string and interpret the `%i` and `%s` as format string accepting a `int` and a `char *` respectively.

Answer (score 4):

```
char* template = "<html>...</html>";
```

is fundamentally no different than

```
char *s = "hello";
```

The name `template` is not special, it's just an ordinary identifier, the name of the variable. (`template` happens to be a keyword in C++, but this is C.)

It would be better to define it as `const`, to enforce the fact that string literals cannot be modified, but it's not mandatory.

Note that `template` itself is not a string. It's a *pointer* to a string. The string itself (defined by the language as "a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null
character") is the sequence starting with `"<html>"` and ending with `"</html>"` and the implicit terminating null character.

And in answer to your second question, `strlen(template)` would work just fine, giving you the length of the string (81 in this case).

Answer (score 2):

I imagine that there is another part of the code that uses this string to format an output string used as a page by the web server.  The strlen function will return the length of the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
char* template = "<html>...</html>";
```

just create a char array  to store data `"<html>...</html>"`,and this array name is `template`,you can change this name to other name you want.When create char array,compiler will add `\0` to the end of array.`strlen` will calculate the length from array start to `\0`(`\0` is no include).

---

I think your IDE will highlight this string is because this string is used in other place.